# Selenium : Persistent Browser Session : timeout after some time

Tags: php, session, testing, selenium, persistent

In order to do things quickly while developing, I'm keeping the browser window opened on a particular page (which is reached after logging in and doing some other stuff that takes around a minute or two). I'm simply assigning the old session id in test case setup and it is working fine with persistent settings.
However there is one little bit of **problem**.
 After every (I think around 30 minutes of inactivity), the browser session times out and running the test case takes 2 minutes. Its not a really big deal but certainly annoying while developing. Is there a way to fix it so that browser default session timeout can be increased.
Im using PHP but it really does not matter if I can find the solution for one language, its easy to figure out for others.